# chrome.extension.onMessage is undefined

Tags: api, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a simple plugin that just does something like this:

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, _, sendResponse) {
    log("Got message from background page: " + msg);
});
```

unfortunately when my panel is loaded the following error is shown:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'addListener' of undefined
```

and according to my tests `chrome.extension.onMessage` is `undefined`

According to this page http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html I should be able to access this chrome API from my page so it has to be something small that I am missing here...

Comment: I have the same problem as @ganoro

Answer (score 3):

**Please note methods `chrome.extension.onRequest` and `chrome.extension.sendRequest`, as originally suggested in this answer, are deprecated as of Chrome 33.**

---

You should use

```
chrome.extension.onRequest
```

instead of

```
chrome.extension.onMessage
```

And in background page or any other extension scripts:

```
chrome.tabs.sendRequest
```

instead of

```
chrome.tabs.sendMessage
```

( the documentation is outdated... alert to google team ;) )

Comment: sendRequest and onRequest is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Just a side note: the Yandex browser (mostly oriented for Russians) which is also based on Chromium still (as of 11/10/2012, ver. 1.0) has the .*Request methods instead of .*Message. Many thanks to Ciprian Amariei for the tip, it saved me a lot of time!

PS: This should actually be a comment to Ciprian Amariei's answer but unfortunately I can't leave comments yet and I though this information could be very helpful to those who develop extensions for Yandex browser.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using the latest Google Chrome version. Older versions don't have the chrome.extension.onMessage API.